# Can't use sudo on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, grub, sudo

After update and reboot I get 'user is not in the sudoers file. This incident will be reported.' when trying to call sudo. The problem is that I don't have a GRUB with revovery option. I try to boot from live cd but I'm not able to access the system partition, only the partition with grub. Can I somehow enable the recovery mode in GRUB? Or boot throw the live CD from first hard drive with some option for that?

Comment: do you get an error when you try to access the system partition?

Comment: if you can get to your boot partition, you can examine */boot/grub/grub.cfg* to see what root partition it loads.  post one of the boot entries from that, and the output of `fdisk -l` (while booted into the LiveCD) so we can help you better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, solved. When I was not able to run it in single mode, this helped: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-boot-ubuntu-linux-rescue-mode/

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu's "recovery" is just another name for "single user mode". You can access it by adding the option **`single`** to the `kernel` line in grub. (It used to be the <kbd>e</kbd> key; I don't know how to do it in grub2.)

Comment: I tried the single but it does not work.

Comment: @martin.malek Please explain what happens, not just 'it does not work'. Does it ask for a password, does it give an error, does it boot normally as if you didn't enter 'single', etc etc

Answer (score 0):

If you're not seeing a Grub menu at boot time, it's probably hidden.  Hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> when booting to unhide the boot menu.  Your recovery options should be there.

*This assumes (1) you're using Grub as your bootloader, and not Win7's boot manager; and (2) you've left Grub in a default configuration.  If you've tweaked your Grub menu, for example to remove the recovery options, this doesn't apply.*